# Как передать параметры между шаблонами twig

Tags: php, twig

у меня следуюшая структура

```
-templates
|-app
 -- home.html.twig
|-inclides
 |-header 
  --header.html.twig 
-base.html.twig
```

home.html.twig наследуется от base.html.twig. А header.html.twig инклюдится в base.html.twig.
Мне надо передать хлебные крошки из home.html.twig в header.html.twig подскажите как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне на очень хочется проверять работает ли но по идее

в base.html.twig делаете например такие блоки и инклудите header.html.twig

```
{% block headvars %}
    {% set foo = 'foo' %}
{% endblock %}

{% include 'header.html.twig' with foo %}

{% block content%}
    <p>123</p>
{% endblock %}
```

в home.html.twig переопределяете их

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block headvars %}
    {% set foo = 'bar' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
    <p>321</p>
{% endblock %}
```

такое никогда не проверял, но по идее должно работать